# F# generic struct constructor and error FS0670

Tags: generics, struct, constructor, f#

I have found some issues about error FS0670 (`This code is not sufficiently generic. ...`) inside StackOverflow, but none of the proposed solution works fine with my issue (I'm a beginner, perhaps I miss in some concepts of F#).

I have the following generic structure that I would like to works only with primitive types only (i.e. int16/32/64 and single/float/decimal).

```
[<Struct>]
type Vector2D<'T when 'T : struct and 'T:(static member get_One: unit -> 'T) and 'T:(static member get_Zero: unit -> 'T) > = 

    val x : 'T
    val y : 'T

    new( xp: 'T, yp: 'T ) = { x = xp; y = yp }
```

But with the new constructor, I get the mentioned error FS0670.

Does somebody knows a possible solution? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error is FS0670? Most people probably don't have the F# error codes memorized, so if you could post the full error message that would help.

Comment: Error FS0670: _This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable ^T  when  ^T : struct and  ^T : (static member get_One : ->  ^T) and  ^T : (static member get_Zero : ->  ^T) could not be generalized because it would escape its scope._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) on structs.

They are only valid for inline functions. What you are trying to do (constrain a type parameter to require specific methods) is not possible in this case.

The closest you can get is to drop the member constraints from the struct and create inline functions that handle the struct for you:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vector2D<'T when 'T : struct> =
    val x : 'T
    val y : 'T

    new( xp: 'T, yp: 'T ) = { x = xp; y = yp }

let inline create< ^T when ^T : struct and ^T:(static member get_One: unit -> ^T) and ^T:(static member get_Zero: unit -> ^T)> (x : ^T) (y : ^T) =
    Vector2D< ^T> (x, y)


create 2.0 3.0 |> ignore
create 4   5   |> ignore
```

Comment: Actually you can have them. The problem is that once you declare them at the type (or struct) level all members must be inline. It seems the F# parser can't deal with an inline `new` keyword, that seems to be rather the issue.