# Getting around "inline but uses private function" for constrained generic struct types

Tags: f#

I want a generic negative number type.

It makes sense to this wrapper type to be a struct, but that means I can't do any validation inside the constructor (`This construct is deprecated: Structs cannot contain 'do' bindings because the default constructor for structs would not execute these bindings`).

So I try moving it outside:

```
[<Struct>]
type Negative<'T> private (x: 'T) =
    member _.Value = x

    new(x: ^a) =
        if x >= LP.GenericZero then
            failwith $"Value must be < 0: {x}"
        Negative x
```

I get: `This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'IComparable'. Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'IComparable' for a type inference variable. The type 'IComparable' does not support the operator 'get_Zero' Consider adding further type constraints.`

I tried `inline new`, but the compiler [doesn't like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175472/f-generic-struct-constructor-and-error-fs0670#comment93247078_53177196).

I tried creating a `static member inline Create` on the type and / or a `let inline create` function on a module, but I can't then make the constructor private because `[FS1113] The value 'create' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible` on compile.

So, how can I create a wrapped type that:

- is a struct
- works with generic number types
- is always validated upon construction?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, but it's a hack and makes me sad.

I avoid having to use `private` because I shadow the type name with an `inline` (and that's the key; I can now use `inline` because the type constructor doesn't have to be `private`) creation function.

Shadowing forces me to use the creation function and not the type's constructor (I think).

```
[<Struct>]
type Negative< ^T>(x: ^T) =
    member _.Value = x

let inline Negative x =
    if x >= LP.GenericZero then
        failwith $"Value must be < 0: {x}"
    Negative x
```